# Assigning and displaying new value in input field

Tags: jquery

By some reason my function does not work. Perhaps I did some syntax error.
Function suppose to take values from two different select tags and display their sum in an input tag. Problem is that none of the tags have id, just names. Names also dynamically change based on a page. Testing revealed that values are grabbed correctly. Please suggest if you find any problems with how function is written.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var productName = document.MainForm.elements["ProductCode"].value;
var selectRightName = "SELECT___" + productName + "___23";
var selectLeftName = "SELECT___" + productName + "___24";
var formQty = "QTY." + productName;

var Quantity1 = document.MainForm.elements[selectRightName].value;
var Quantity2 = document.MainForm.elements[selectLeftName].value;

if (Quantity1 == 75)
    Quantity1 = 1
else if (Quantity1 == 196)
    Quantity1 = 2
else if (Quantity1 == 197)
    Quantity1 = 3
else if (Quantity1 == 198)
    Quantity1 = 4
else if (Quantity1 == 199)
    Quantity1 = 5

if (Quantity2 == 76)
    Quantity2 = 1
else if (Quantity2 == 200)
    Quantity2 = 2
else if (Quantity2 == 201)
    Quantity2 = 3
else if (Quantity2 == 202)
    Quantity2 = 4
else if (Quantity2 == 203)
    Quantity2 = 5

var QtyUpdated = Quantity1 + Quantity2;

var Qty = document.MainForm.elements[formQty].value;



$(document).ready(function()
     $('input[name=selectRightName]').change( function() {

    MainForm.elements[formQty].value = QtyUpdated;
    $('input[name=formQty]').html(QtyUpdated);
 }

  }); 

})

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have some issues with your JS:

1. You haven't actually defined a function - you have script that gets executed once, immediately, when the page loads.
2. When adding the values, you should use `parseInt()` in order to convert the string you get from the text box into an integer you can add:

   ```
   var QtyUpdated = parseInt(Quantity1, 10) + parseInt(Quantity2, 10);
   ```
3. `$('input[name=formQty]').html(QtyUpdated);` doesn't seem right - `formQty`, the variable has a value assigned to it based on the product name. This jQuery selector looks for an `<input>` element named `formQty` - that doesn't seem like what you want it to do.
4. You're missing semi-colons (`;`) in all your `if-else` blocks - while optional, I'd recommend against relying on the JavaScript engine insertion. It can lead to hard to trace issues.
5. Since you are already including jQuery, you could use a lot more of it, making it easier on yourself when getting and setting values in text boxes

---

**Update**

You haven't shown your HTML so this may not be a drop in replacement for your existing JS but here some code that fixes some of the problems:

```
var productName = $('input[name=ProductCode]').val();
var selectRightName = "SELECT___" + productName + "___23";
var selectLeftName = "SELECT___" + productName + "___24";
var formQty = "QTY." + productName;

function updateValues(){
    var Quantity1 = $('select[name=' + selectRightName + ']').val();
    var Quantity2 = $('select[name=' + selectLeftName + ']').val();

    if (Quantity1 == 75){
        Quantity1 = 1;
    }
    else if (Quantity1 == 196){
        Quantity1 = 2;
    }
    else if (Quantity1 == 197)
        Quantity1 = 3;
    }
    else if (Quantity1 == 198){
        Quantity1 = 4;
    }
    else if (Quantity1 == 199){
        Quantity1 = 5;
    }

    if (Quantity2 == 76){
        Quantity2 = 1;
    }
    else if (Quantity2 == 200){
        Quantity2 = 2;
    }
    else if (Quantity2 == 201){
        Quantity2 = 3;
    }
    else if (Quantity2 == 202){
        Quantity2 = 4;
    }
    else if (Quantity2 == 203){
        Quantity2 = 5;
    }

    var QtyUpdated = parseInt(Quantity1,10) + parseInt(Quantity2,10);

    $('input[name=' + formQty + ']').val(QtyUpdated);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select[name=' + selectRightName + ']').change( function() {
        updateValues();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for all your points. All make sense. On #3> formQty is a name of input that is different for each page, just like select is also different. I changed the script as you suggested but it still doesn't work. I am not sure how to correct your point #1. Function must execute on each select change, Right and Left.

Comment: @Alexica Yes, but you see, you *have no function*. To create a named function, you must use the syntax `function myFunction(){ //function body}` and invoke it as `myFunction()` - you're not doing that. Please see my updated answer with example code that might help.

Answer (score 1):

On top of the already stated issues, the end part there has some syntax issues:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name=selectRightName]').change( function() {

        MainForm.elements[formQty].value = QtyUpdated;
        $('input[name=formQty]').html(QtyUpdated);


  }); 

})
```

Comment: So for function to execute on each select change, I need to drop    $(document).ready(function(){}) from the statement?

Comment: your curly brackets were in the wrong places, you were missing one right after `function()` and you had an extra one at the bottom.

Comment: yes, that was a good catch. Thank you. But I still need $(document).ready(function(){...}) to execute the function on each select change?

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){...})` is used to execute your code once the DOM is fully loaded.  See the jquery page http://api.jquery.com/ready/